# Upload file using Curl and receive them in Laravel method

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I have been trying to upload file to using curl using laravel app end point.

Below code is on separate server.

```
$header = $this->getCurlHeader();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);   
$cfile = new \CURLFile($this->filePath . $this->csvFile,  'text/csv','text.csv');
//print_r($cfile);exit;
$postData = array('csv' => $cfile);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$hhtpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//$this->dbg($hhtpCode);
$this->dbg(json_decode($response,1),1);
```

And receiving end in laravel app hosted on different server.

```
public function insert(Request $request, $feed=''){
     //return response()->json(var_dump($request->all()));
     //return response()->json("here in insert");
     return response()->json($_FILES);
     echo "here";
     dd($_FILES);
}
```

It returns me empty response.
I am able to verify curl request using headers.

Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this on the source server instead:

```
$target_url = 'https://mywebsite.com'; // Write your URL here
$dir = '/var/www/html/storage/test.zip'; // full directory of the file

$cFile = curl_file_create($dir);
$post = array('file'=> $cFile); // Parameter to be sent

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

From the destination server, print the request sent.

```
public function insert(Request $request){
    dd($request->file);
}
```

Comment: What about receiving script

Comment: Not able to receive any thing in receiving script

Comment: @ShakirBhatt I've updated the sample for destination server

Comment: Thanks. Tried `dd($request->file);` but it prints nothing. Can i get in touch if you don't mind.

Comment: I have the answer but i couldn't post it as I have been banned for posting.

Answer (score 0):

please use curlfile method to upload files.

```
if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['identity_doc']))
            {

                    foreach($_FILES['identity_doc'] as $key => $file)
                    {
                        $data['document'.$i]= new CURLFile($_FILES['identity_doc']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['identity_doc']['type'][$i],$_FILES['identity_doc']['name'][$i]);
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't have from-data. My file is at some path.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fileName=$_FILES['resume']['name']; 
    $type=$_FILES['resume']['type'];
    $tempPathname=$_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($tempPathname, "r");
    $POST_DATA = fread($handle, filesize($tempPathname));

    $url="https://objectstorage.region-name.oraclecloud.com/p/par-id/n/namespace`enter code here`/b/bucket-name/o/images/".$fileName;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
         CURLOPT_URL => $url,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
         CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
         CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
         CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$POST_DATA ,
         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           'Content-Type: '.$type,
         ),
     ));
     $response = curl_exec($curl);
     $err = curl_error($curl);
    
     curl_close($curl);
     
     if ($response) {
        echo 'error';
     } else { 
         echo $url;
     }
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="resume">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```