# Error when trying to send file in CURL POST call

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am trying to make a call from my Laravel application to the Bullhorn API to convert a document to HTML, but it looks like the file isn't being attached to the call. Below is my code:

```
$data = curl_file_create("full/path/to/file.docx", 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'testcv');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

However I receive the following 500 error:

> Bad File Uploaded: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

When I try to set the `Content-Type` explicitly:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
));
```

I still receive a 500 error, just slightly different:

> Bad File Uploaded: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

I don't believe it's an issue with the Bullhorn API because executing the following call through the command line works fine:

```
curl -X POST "https://restXXX.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/{corptoken}/resume/convertToHtml?format=docx&BhRestToken={bhRestToken}" -F "file=@full\path\to\file.docx"
```

I assume that for some reason the file isn't being attached in my PHP call but I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269636/upload-file-using-curl-and-receive-them-in-laravel-method this should help

Comment: @AdityaThakur I've seen that thread already but as far as I can see, it's the same as my code. I tried using `new CURLFile` instead of the procedural style but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The `content-type: multipart/form-data` uses boundary parameter for encapsulation, you can pass the boundary value as a string

`'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7da24f2e50046'`

Boundary is a string of "--" followed by a random string.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: I changed the `Content-Type` to the above but now I am getting the following 400 error: `No File Uploaded!!`. That looks very generic

Comment: 400 would mean a bad request, would require some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If I ever have any weird problems with requests, I always put the request into [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and test it there since it compiles most of the headers and options for you, then just hit the code button on the top right to generate code in whatever language you want.

For your case you could datadump (dd) out your $data variable and copy it into one of the postman fields then set the url as well as the request type then run it and see what you get back.

Just a suggestion on how to debug a problem like this, hope it helps! good luck!